# What are @property and @synthesize used for in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

What is the use of *@property* and *@synthesize*? Can you explain with an example please?

Comment: help yourself, read a book or Apple's Objective C introduction: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html

Answer (score 6):

Really short answer: They create accessors for the ivars.

There are [some examples on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Properties). Look at those.

Answer (score 3):

From the [apple developer library](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/articles/ocProperties.html):

> You can think of a property declaration as being equivalent to declaring two accessor methods. Thus

```
@property float value;
```

> is equivalent to:

```
- (float)value;

- (void)setValue:(float)newValue;
```

And by using @synthesize, the compiler creates accessor methods for you (see more [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAccessorMethods.html))

Answer (score 1):

```
// Sample for @property and @sythesize //

@interface ClassA

  NSString *str; 

@end

@implementation ClassA

@end

The Main Function main()
```

//make sure you #import ClassA

```
ClassA *obj=[[ClassA alloc]init];

obj.str=@"XYZ"; // That time it will give the error that we don't have the getter or setter method. To use string like this we use @property and @sythesize
```